# Advertising poster for Ling SE

Tags: discussion, advertising

I would like to advertise about Linguistics SE on my department bulletin boards. However, I'm not good at making good looking flyers/posters/anything. Is there one I can use somewhere? If not, would someone mind making one? It doesn't need to be super awesome, just enough to catch the eye and make linguistics students curious, one page size.

Comment: You wrote "Ling SO" but maybe you meant "Ling SE"? I fixed it. :)

Comment: We like it when our users make the flyers themselves. Some sites *have* had posters made for them by our design team, but those sites are few and far between. The better option *is* for you guys to make it and then share it amongst yourselves. If you feed adventurous, you may consider asking over in [Graphic Design](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) if anyone would like to lend a hand. :)

Comment: You might draw inspiration from [english.se]: [English.SE pamphlet - hang up or hand out to your friends and classmates](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/2155) (and we did get Jin to make a PDF with the same style from the text we provided [here](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/promoting-english-language-usage)/[ici](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/269/promotion-de-french-language-and-usage-promoting-french-language-and-usage)).

Comment: Nate, are you still willing to make these posters? :D

Answer (score 1):

If you can come up with some text, I'll do my best to do the design. It won't be a miracle but hopefully it will at least match the one they have at English Language and Usage.

Anyone knows if the logo is available as vector graphics? What size do you want it to be? A4?

Answer (score 0):

We have some Community Promotion Ads and ad ideas: [Community ad ideas for Linguistics](https://linguistics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/468/community-ad-ideas-for-linguistics). Some of these could be scaled up and used as posters.

Example:

[image: linguistics ad]

Of course, you'd need to add the URL for a printed poster.

Comment: I am the author, I wouldn't really like this to be used as a public poster but if someone wants to, please contact me about it.