# Community ad ideas for Linguistics

Tags: discussion, promotion, advertising

In order to promote this site, Alenanno created a community promotion ad to be placed on related Stack Exchange sites. (Currently this is only English Language and Usage, since ads are only enabled for graduated sites, and the other language sites remain in beta.)

Do people have other ideas for ads? Post them here.

Comment: I've added the tag **[Featured]** so that it appears on the main site and it can receive more visits.

Answer (score 2):

Alenanno's second idea (draft):

[image: Linguistics Stack Exchange]

From discussion in chat:

> I thought that it might wrongly suggest to EL&U users that linguistics is just for etymology.
> Perhaps add some more reflexes of **dn̥ǵʰu*- in English (*tongue*) and other languages.
> One possibility: put arrows starting from *dn̥ǵʰu* to several daughter words, the top one of which would be the *lingu*- that you currently have.
>
> Why "just"? It's an aspect of it. For example, I [did this](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2539/2217) for the Anime SE, but we all know Anime is not just Naruto.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Alenanno's first ad ([submitted to EL&U here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3400/community-promotion-ads-2013/3479#3479)):

[image: Linguistics Stack Exchange]

Alternate version with the same font in the reflection ([SVG source](https://gist.github.com/4362126)):

[image: Linguistics Stack Exchange]

Alenanno said of the alternate version:

> "Linguistics" written in small caps was on purpose. The IPA shadow below is more intended to be a representation of "what's behind the words" rather than an actual projected shadow of a word. I like yours, but it changes what I meant to convey with mine.

Comment: Yes, that was my rationale. :D

Answer (score 0):

What about a quasi-Swadesh list, displaying corresponding terms in several languages? The problem is that terms like "linguistics" will be loanwords in most languages, so I'm not sure how to tie it into the ad.

Maybe use the words for "language", "stack", and "exchange". English in bold, on the left.

Example:

```
English       Dutch   Spanish  Lithuanian Russian Greek          Albanian  Hindustani
**language**  taal    idioma   kalbà      jazýk   ghlóssa        gjuha     bhāṣā
**stack**     stapel  pila     ?          kúcha   sorós          grumbull? dhu'ām̐rā
**exchange**  beurs   bolsa    birža      bírzha  khrimatistírjo bursa     bājār

Linguistics Stack Exchange
```

(The "stack" translations should really be for the computing term, but those will just be English loanwords so it doesn't really work. I'm using Indo-European languages for now.)